# SQL Server XML PATH removing XML

Tags: sql-server, xml

In SQL Server, if I run the following query

```
SELECT Name FROM Roles
FOR XML PATH('')
```

I get

```
<Name>Admin</Name><Name>SuperAdmin</Name><Name>UltraAdmin</Name>
```

which makes sense. However, if I concatenate the Name field with another character, it takes the enclosing XML elements away:

```
SELECT '_' + Name + '_' FROM Roles
FOR XML PATH('')
```

I get

```
_Admin__SuperAdmin__UltraAdmin_
```

I was expecting

```
<Name>_Admin_</Name><Name>_SuperAdmin_</Name><Name>_UltraAdmin_</Name>
```

What the dilleo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510469.aspx) on usage of `FOR XML PATH`:

> ... computed columns or nested scalar queries that do not specify
>   column alias will generate columns without any name.

To get the expected result use an alias:

```
SELECT '_' + Name + '_' AS Name FROM Roles
FOR XML PATH('')
```